# c# loop and get the values of all datetimepicker in form programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, datetimepicker

I have a form with multiple `TextBox` and `NumericUpDown` And `DateTimePicker`. I want to get programmatically all value of this controls and insert them to sql server data base

I tried this code

```
 foreach (Control contrl in this.Controls)
 {
     if (contrl.Name != "")
     {
           vv.Add(contrl.Text);
           //MessageBox.Show(contrl.Name);   
     }

}
```

it gets me the correct values of `TextBox` and `NumericUpDown` but not `DateTimePicker`

Comment: This is because the value of the `DateTimePicker` is stored in `Value` not in `Text` like in a `Textbox`

Comment: You'll probably have to cast to a DateTimePicker and check if the cast succeeded like this: `var picker = control as DateTimePicker; if (picker != null) { var value = ((DateTimePicker)picker).Value; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTimePicker` and `NumericUpDown` use `Value` property to get it's content, `TextBox` use `Text` property.

So you need to check the type of each control

```
foreach (Control contrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (contrl.Name != "")
    {
         if(contrl is TextBox)
            vv.Add(((TextBox)contrl).Text);     
         else if(contrl is DateTimePicker)
            vv.Add(((DateTimePicker)contrl).Value);
         else if(contrl is NumericUpDown)
            vv.Add(((NumericUpDown)contrl).Value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does "vv" came from? is that a declaration or variables? @iswanto San

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimePicker
```

does not store its value in "Text" Property, rather than it stores in "Value" Property

so try to add one more condition in this loop,

```
foreach (Control contrl in this.Controls)
 {
      if (contrl.Name != "")
      {
         vv.Add(contrl.Text);
         //MessageBox.Show(contrl.Name);   
      }

      if (contrl.Name == "YOurDateTimePickerControlName")
      {
         vv.Add(contrl.Value.ToString());
      }

 }
```

Comment: Where does that "vv" came from? i do not understand. @Mr. Go